# Spinner with custom text font and color

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I want to use custom font and color in Spinner. I can't modify them directly in `<spinner/>`

Here's my code

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
                android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
                android:backgroundTint="#d9d9d9"
                android:entries="@array/dropdown_main" />
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Text font is Product Sans Bold, color is #333333

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you can make a custom xml file in layout folder where you can add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#333333"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textStyle="bold"  />
```

And then in your code mention it like this:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.array_name, R.layout.custom_spinner) // where array_name consists of the items to show in Spinner
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner) // where custom-spinner is mycustom xml file.
```

And then set the adapter.

Answer (score 15):

A heads up before you get started: To add the font, you'll either want to set a minimum API version of 26 or include the Support Library v26.0 (for support starting at API version 16).  This example shows how to use the support library; the only real difference is the `<font-family>` using the `app` or `res-auto` namespace instead of `android`.

You can keep the spinner as is but add a `theme` value to your XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5pt"
    android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
    android:backgroundTint="#d9d9d9"
    android:entries="@array/dropdown_main"
    android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme"  />
```

Your `styles.xml` can contain the theme:

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#333333</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/product_sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

To add the font, you'll need to do a few things:

1. Add a font folder: Right-click your `res` folder and choose *New > Android resource directory*.  Make sure you pick a resource type of "Font" (and probably the name as well.)
2. Add the Product Sans font file to your project from somewhere like https://befonts.com/product-sans-font.html.
3. Right-click the `font` folder under `res` and choose *New > Font resource file*.  Name the file `product_sans.xml`.
4. List your added fonts:

Make sure you add the `app` namespace here if you're using the support library.  Otherwise, if you're at SDK Version 26 or above, you can reference the `android` namespace.

```
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:font="@font/product_sans_regular" app:fontWeight="400" app:fontStyle="normal" />
    <font app:font="@font/product_sans_italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:fontStyle="italic" />
    <font app:font="@font/product_sans_bold" app:fontWeight="700" app:fontStyle="normal" />
    <font app:font="@font/product_sans_bold_italic" app:fontWeight="700" app:fontStyle="italic" />
</font-family>
```

More info about fonts in your XML can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: `android:fontFamily` is supported starting from API level 16, not 26.

Comment: @AleksN. - Correct! It requires the support library, which I mention but never call out the API level supported there.