# how to create spinner like this in android studio?

Tags: android, android-spinner

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmVdo.png

I want to know how to create background for this spinner in xml.

Comment: You can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129212/spinner-with-custom-text-font-and-color/52129693#52129693

Comment: Refer to this blog for help. https://mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a custom adapter for spinner but there is a easy way like this

```
<Relativelayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background=your color>

<Spinner android:id="@+id/fragment_filter_sp_users"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_bottom"
   />
  </Relativelayout>
```