# how to change the text on an Android Spinner view element

Tags: android, styles, spinner, textcolor

the many other answers do tell me that android:textColor is the one that does the trick. However no matter what attribute I change in my styles, the app still shows default Black text.
In fact, I cannot even see an attribute called textColor or the likes of it in the layout editor - attribs tab.

Comment: Where is that piece of code *However no matter what attribute I change in my styles, the app still shows default Black text* ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [Spinner with custom text font and color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129212/)

Here you can make a custom xml file in layout folder where you can add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#333333"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textStyle="bold"  />
```

And then in your code mention it like this:

```
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.array_name, R.layout.custom_spinner) // where array_name consists of the items to show in Spinner
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner) // where custom-spinner is 

mycustom xml file.
```

And then set the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my solution would work,

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" /> 


And then change your declaration of the spinner to use the R.layout.spinner_item:

ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```